# Trouble converting Crosstab SQL into VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, crosstab

I am having trouble converting/formatting a crosstab query SQL for VBA.  I am getting a syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'TRANSFORM' keyword.

I know that having the SQL start with the TRANSFORM command is most likely the issue, but after searching I have yet to find a solution.

I changed the "strSQl" to "strCrosstabQuery, but am still returning the same error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

See below for my current VBA.

---

```
Sub NewWorkRegional()

Sheets("Create Raw").Select
Range("A2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Clear

strConn = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=XXXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=KRATDAN;Data Source=DWPROD"
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 0

Dim strCrosstabQuery As String

 strCrosstabQuery = "TRANSFORM Count(DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders.work_order_number) AS CountOfwork_order_number" & _
"SELECT DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders.sub_type_level_2" & _
"FROM DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders" & _
"WHERE (((DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders.reporting_region)='pacific') AND ((DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders.create_date) Between Date()-16 And Date()-3))" & _
"GROUP BY DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_orders.sub_type_level_2" & _
"PIVOT [create_date]+7-Weekday([create_date],7);"


'updated line above

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strCrosstabQuery, cn

Sheets("Results").Range("B92").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: if you paste the data table and the SQL statement (as a query) into Access does it work correctly?

Comment: Sorry, new to VBA here.  The SQL statement will work in Access to output a Crosstab table.  Not sure what you mean about pasting the data table.

Comment: yes, that is what I was asking. Does the `crosstab` statement work in Access (or actually on your SQL-Server) ...  I don't SQL-Server too well, but what if you put `#` around the `Date()-16` and `Date()-3`? Does that help ... maybe on the `PIVOT` statement as well.

Comment: The dates should be OK as far as I can tell.  I think # are only needed when using a an actual date (i.e. #11/17/2015#).

Comment: In access I am pretty sure you need them when stating a explicit date or using any type of variable that provides the date ...

Comment: Tried that, continue to have the same sytax error: "expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'TRANSFORM' keyword."

Comment: Need to add spaces after your line continuations.  EG right now you have `...FROM DNS_SBX_rpt_v_dm_all_work_ordersWHERE ...`

Comment: Implemented spaces; receiving same error message.